# Dataflow template is not taking input parameters

Tags: dataflow

I have a dataflow template created with below command

```
 mvn compile exec:java \
 -Dexec.mainClass=com.StarterPipeline \
 -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner \
              --project=jason-qa \
              --stagingLocation=gs://jason_test/dataflow/staging \
              --region=asia-east1 \
              --zone=asia-east1-a \
              --subnetwork=regions/asia-east1/subnetworks/dmz-asia-east1 \
              --templateLocation=gs://jason_test/dataflow/Template \
              --campaignId="
```

Executing Templates with below command

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run jason203 \
--project=jason-qa \
--region=asia-east1 \
--gcs-location gs://jason_test/dataflow/Template \
--parameters campaignId=run-test323,output=gs://jason_test/dataflow/counts
```

code copy from Count example and have few changes

```
public interface MyOptions extends PipelineOptions {

    @Description("campaign id")
    @Required
    @Default.String("default-test123")
    ValueProvider<String> getCampaignId();

    void setCampaignId(ValueProvider<String> campaignId);
}

  static void run(MyOptions options) {
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
String id = options.getCampaignId().get();
p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()))
    .apply(new Count())
    .apply(MapElements.via(new FormatAsTextFn()))
    .apply("WriteCounts", TextIO.write().to(options.getOutput() + id));
p.run();
```

}

from the DataFlow Job summary --> Pipeline options
I can find the info:   campaignId   run-test323

but the result in bucket, file name is -00000-of-00003(It should be run-test323-00000-of-00003)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should remove the .get() in the code, then it will work